# google app engine python rot13

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

I am having difficulty trying to figuring out what is wrong with my code, I am trying to make a rot13 program using python and google app engine. I have been trying to figure out what the problem is but I cant, my code works fine till the getting the value from the text box, but when I pass it to the rot13 function it gives me an 500 error, Thanks in advance

```
import webapp2
import cgi
form = """<form method="post">
    <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>"""

def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote=True)

def rot13(s):
    regular = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ciper13 = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
    s = s.translate(s.maketrans(regular, ciper13))
    return s

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self):
        self.response.write(form)

    def get(self):
        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        text = self.request.get('text')
        text = escape_html(text)
        text = rot13(text)
        self.response.write(text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
>>> s = s.translate(s.maketrans(regular, ciper13))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

`maketrans` is an attribute of the `string` *module*, not of individual string instances.

You need to import the `string` module (`import string`) and change your code to:

```
>>> s = s.translate(string.maketrans(regular, ciper13))
```

An alternative approach would be to use the built in rot-13 encoding:

```
>>> s = u'foo'
>>> s.encode('rot-13')
'sbb'
```